# Determine If all Values in Dictionary pairs are equal

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary consisting of Points and Forces like this:

```
public Dictionary<Point, Force> PointForceSet;
```

I want to write a function that will tell me if all of the forces contained are the same. So far I have this:

```
public bool IsUniform()
{

    foreach (var item in PointForceSet)
    {
       //?
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to determine if all of the values in the key,value pairs are equal?

Comment: If `PointForceSet` is empty, what should `IsUniform` return?

Comment: It should return false

Comment: What is `Force`? Does it override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Yes it does. It is an immutable custom class

Answer (score 4):

If your values have meaningful default comparer (like numbers), it will be enough:

```
public bool IsUniform()
{    
    return PointForceSet.Values.Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

But if there are classes (like your `Force`) remember to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, to allow real distinction between `Force` object instances, f.e.:

```
class Force
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Force other = obj as Force;
        return other != null && X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 17 * X + Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just check if the values are Distinct. That doesn't solve the problem because you still can have different Points.

Comment: @SidBurn, _"simplest way to determine if **all of the values** in the key,value pairs are equal"_

Comment: Note that this will return false for an empty set, which is conceptually wrong...

Comment: Ups, you are right, your solution is right. Seems i over complicated it. I somehow read he wanted to check if the Pair itself are distinct not just the values.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Conceptually wrong, but asked by OP.

Comment: @Vache OP didn't specify behavior on an empty dictionary...

Comment: @ReedCopsey he did in the comments

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to extract out the first value, and check to guarantee the others all match:

```
public bool IsUniform()
{
    var values = PointForceSet.Values;
    if (values.Count == 0)
        return false; // Normally would be true - handling your req. based on comments

    var first = values.First();
    return values.Skip(1).All(v => v.Equals(first));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var first = values.First();` ? Also this breaks if `PointForceSet` is empty.

Comment: This will throw an exception if called on an empty dictionary.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Added a check in there - not sure what the proper behavior should be though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `KeyValuePair` is a `struct`.  It doesn't *have* a reference.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Conceptually all of the items in an empty set are equal to each other.

Comment: @Servy Which is why I returned true on my edit.

Comment: @Servy are they not also all different from one-another?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, they are.  Any predicate is always true of all items in an empty set.  If the predicate is `item => false` then all of the items in the set still fulfill the predicate of "is never a match".  There's a fancy technical term for this property of an empty set, but it's eluding me at the moment.

Comment: @Servy [Vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) would be that term!

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
PointForceSet.Distinct()
```

passing in an

```
IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<Point, Force>>
```

implementation.

If there are items in the dictionary and .Distinct() returns only one item, all items are the "same" according to your comparer code.

Answer (score 1):

To allow for short circuiting as soon as a non-equal pair is found the ideal solution is to simply iterate through the sequence, comparing each item to the first.

```
public static bool AreSame<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            return true;
        var first = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
            if (!comparer.Equals(first, iterator.Current))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that explicit enumeration of the iterator is used to both prevent iteration of the sequence multiple times, as well as to support empty sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Another efficient way using [`HashSet<Force>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public bool IsUniform(ICollection<Force> forces)
{
    if (forces == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("forces");
    if (!forces.Any()) return false;
    var set = new HashSet<Force> { forces.First() };
    return set.SetEquals(forces);
}

// ...
bool allEqual = IsUniform(PointForceSet.Values);
```

which works since you've overridden `Equals` + `GetHashCode` as commented.

Comment: 1) You're iterating the source sequence multiple times 2) there's no point in having a set when that set will never have more than one item in it.

Comment: oh, and you should probably rename your method, now that you've reversed it's meaning.

Comment: You're still iterating the source set 3 times, and you're still using a set when you only really need a single item.  This part isn't wrong, per say, it's just wasteful.

Comment: @Servy: now you've lost me there. The name is OP's name and  i just provide a different approach for OP's requirement to check if a given sequence "is uniform" (has no duplicates). I'm creating the set only with a single item in it and `SetEquals` stops as soon as it has found a duplicate. So the only redundancy is the single item which is checked against itself which is negligible.

Comment: @Servy: also, i don't understand where i'm iterating the source 3 times.  `!forces.Any()` just needs to "look" if there is at least one(`return enumerator.MoveNext()`), `forces.First` is nearly the same as `forces[0]` and `set.SetEquals(forces)` is quite efficient. This apporach does also not need to count the result as the `Distinct().Count()` way.

Comment: As I said, you create a set that only ever has one item in it.  But because you're using a set you're allocating a buffer that you never use, you're checking the hash code of every item in addition to its `Equals` method, the set needs to manage the overhead of finding buckets, etc. all instead of just comparing the one item you have to each other item in the set.  It's just wasteful, for no particularly good reason.

Comment: As for the multiple iteration of the set, imagine that this sequence is actually an `IQueryable` that represents a database query.  For each of the calls to `Any`, `First`, and `SetEquals` you're executing that query against the database.  And then there are sequences that might cause side effects when you start executing the query, doing those 3 times could be real bad, there are sequences that might contain something like LINQ's `Join`, `Intersect`, `GroupBy` that eagerly perform a bunch of expensive operations on the first call to `MoveNext`, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand your objections. Yes, the `HashSet` does only ever contain a single item and every item in the dictionary's `ValueCollection` needs to be checked against the single item in it (as long as all are equal, oterwise `SetEquals` breaks immediately).  But what exactly is inefficient in using `HashSet.SetEquals`? There is no allocation of buffer other than for a single item and the `GetHashCode` + `Equals` check needs to be done also in a every other implementation (like `Distiunct`). Finding buckets in a set which contains a single item is not so difficult, is it?

Comment: The requirement was to write a method that checks if all values in a `Dictionary<Point, Force>` are equal, no more, no less. However, there might be room for improvement of course, f.e. make the parameter a `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: When you create a set it doesn't create a buffer of size one.  It creates a buffer that can hold a number of items so that you can add more without a re-allocation.  You are correct that all of the solutions using `Distinct` are also comparing hash codes in addition to equality needlessly, and that your code isn't alone in that regards.  I'm not advocating that those are the best solution to this problem.

Comment: It only takes a few lines of code to just only iterate the sequence once.  I don't see any compelling benefit to trying to avoid solving the general problem correctly.

Comment: @Servy: you're right, the current implementation of `HashSet` will create a buffer for three elements since that is the first prime >= 1. Isn't this  micro-optimization par excellence since only one set needs to be created? However, i agree that my method is not the best way, neither in terms of readabily nor in terms of performance. But this was not meant to be used as a general extension for `IEnumerable<T>` anyway. It works, `SetEquals` is meaningful and it's efficient enough (in my opinion).

Comment: The use of a `HashSet` is certainly way less important than the fact that you're iterating the sequence 3 times, yes, and the redundant checking of the hash codes is going to be way more noticeable than a small wasted buffer.  The fact that one of the several things that I mentioned is a microoptimization doesn't mean that your code is efficient or even that it works, because strictly speaking it doesn't, due to the multiple enumeration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58255/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-servy).

Answer (score 0):

This should work if `Force` class overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Otherwise implement an `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to the constructor

```
public bool IsUniform()
{    
    return new HashSet<Force>(PointForceSet.Values).Count == 1;
}
```